# Laravel 8 returning 200 status on validation error (on server), but works fine on localhost (422 status code)

Tags: php, laravel

This is the code

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'cr_number' => 'required|numeric|unique:companies,cr_number',
        'cr_image' => 'required|max:2000|mimes:jpg,jpeg,pdf,png,webp',
        'applies_vat' => 'required|boolean|in:1,0,true,false|max:255',
        'vat_number' => 'nullable|numeric|required_if:applies_vat,1,true',
        'vat_certificate' => 'nullable|max:2000|mimes:jpg,jpeg,pdf,png,webp|required_if:applies_vat,1,true',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:companies,email',
        'category_id' => 'required|exists:categories,id',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status'=> 'error', 
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'errors'    => $validator->errors()
        ],422);
    }
```

This is the response on actual server:
[image: Server Response]

and this one on localhost
[image: localhost response]

Request body: [image: Body]

Response headers localhost: [image: Response Header]

Response headers server: [image]

Other functions are working fine and returning Json format, just this one is not working.

**EDIT:**
The problem seems to be related to the server itself, I have tried another server and it was working fine

Comment: You should make sure you're sending the request with the `Accept: application/json` header. because many tools like Postman, etc ... may not add this header for you by default. Double check it.

Comment: it is already added as you can see in the image link

Comment: headers count in localhost is 12 but in the server is 7, please add the full request body to the question.

Comment: I have added the body, and the headers you mentioned @PooyaSabramooz

Answer (score 0):

In server header Content-Type must be `application/json` but in localhost headers its `text/html`.

You can set a Content-Type header manually if you need to override the one Postman sends automatically.

So please add Content-Type header to the request and set it to `application/json`.